# Are C files renamed to C++ are going to be compilable with C++ compilers after renaming?

Tags: c++, c

C files renamed to C++ are going to be compilable with C++ compilers after renaming?
So I have 25 C files and 1 C++ file I do not want to create Make files or anething like that. I want to turn all that C files into C++ so will simple renaming work or what shall I do?

Comment: This user is apparently spamming SO with the same question phrased slightly differently. Please don't respond to any more of his posts on this topic.

Comment: 222 questions asked with only 812 rep...insane

Comment: Thats also 222 questions in 5 months, or around 1.5 questions every single day (weekends, holidays, etc).  I don't want to discourage a learner, but this seems extreme and potentially abusive.

Comment: Asking is siple while you are well paid for it=) I honestly do not care about rep=)

Comment: But -5 ?!? EVEN FOR A STUPID QUESTION!!!

Comment: No. Not -5 for a stupid question. -5 for spamming SO with the same question a half dozen times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes.  You will have to worry about variables named `class` and such, the `sizeof` a character literal, and name mangling, and some other rarely encountered issues.  If you're converting C99 to C++, you'll have to drop some C99 features.

With regards to name mangling, reference any C symbols by using `extern "C"`.  A common idiom is:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern int myGlobal;
extern int myFunction(void);
/* etc */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends somwhat (maybe) on the compiler, but gcc will compile / mangle them as C++ once you name them that way.

This was the big advantage of C++, back in the day. Valid C is valid C++ (mostly), so moving to the new language was trivial.

Comment: I use windows... Visual Studio 08

Comment: I was assuming you were trying to move C code into a C++ project, and not the other way around.

Comment: Valid C is not necessarily valid C++.

Comment: And who is voting up this answer?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, you don't give us enough to go on, but if you are asking about the Microsoft and /or GCC compilers they will, in the absence of explicit information, base the way they compile a file on its extension. If you rename  a .cpp file to .c, it will be compiled as C source, rather than C++ (and vice versa), but this in no way means that the file will compile without errors.

Answer (score 0):

They may or may not compile as C++ files.  The languages are close, but not the same.  For example, in C, a variable may be named 'new' but in C++ that is a keyword, so

```
int new = 12;
```

will compile in C, but not in C++.  Same for 'class', 'public',... etc C++ keywords.

The overall goal was to make it either compile, or fail to compile, but never compile wrongly.  Although I'm not sure if they 100% succeeded.

Comment: The languages are not particularly close. There are many questions on SO illustrating this.